# How to add a vertical scroll bar to Android layout with many children in the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have been trying to figure out how to ensure the screen can be scrolled vertically as there are many radio buttons and they don't fit on the screen. I have tried most of the solutions posted on Stackoverflow, but I keep getting errors, here is my layout code at my last attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSharing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioSharingYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_sharing_yes"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioSharingNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_sharing_no" />

</RadioGroup>

 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioInternet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioInternetYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_internet_yes"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioInternetNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_internet_no" />

</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioMap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMapYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_map_yes"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMapNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_map_no" />

</RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioCalling"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioCallingYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_calling_yes"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioCallingNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_calling_no" />

</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioDatabase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioDatabaseYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_database_yes"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioDatabaseNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_database_no" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_display" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The error I am getting is : "ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Any advice would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but have you tried making a linear layout the direct child and putting the radio buttons in that? Please feel free to ignore if that's nonsense :)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek That's the correct answer, sorta.  `ScrollView` can only have 1 direct child.  The standard way of getting around it is to create a `LinearLayout` as the direct child, then put everything in it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a closer look at your nesting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <RadioGroup
 ......
 </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You should have LinearLayout entirely within ScrollView, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <RadioGroup
 ......
 </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Excellent that worked perfectly! I am convinced I tried every combination of nesting before posting my question, seems I tried them all except this one! :(

:)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The first answer has got one mistake.

**instead**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
 ......
</ScrollView>
```

**use**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


 ......
  </ScrollView>
```